# Узнать высоту элемента через Javascript, если она прописана в стилевом файле

Tags: javascript, html

Как я могу получить атрибут `height` элемента через Javascript, если он прописан в стилевом файле `style.css`?

style.css:

```
.menu_bottom {
    height: 100px;
}
```

index.php:

```
<div id="menu_bottom" class="menu_bottom">
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        alert(document.getElementById("menu_bottom").style.height);
    </script>
```

Нужно, чтобы сообщение `alert(...)` показало высоту данного элемента (просто число, без единицы измерения).

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15615552/5812238

Answer (score 10, accepted):

проще всего использовать [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) :

```
$('#menu_bottom').height();
```

без jQuery можно использовать:

```
var h = document.getElementById('menu_bottom').clientHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('menu_bottom').offsetHeight;
var h = document.getElementById('menu_bottom').scrollHeight;
```

**clientHeight** высота содержимого вместе с полями padding, но без полосы прокрутки.

**offsetHeight** «внешняя» высота блока, включая рамки.

**scrollHeight** полная внутренняя высота, включая прокрученную область.

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = document.getElementById("menu_bottom");
var height = window.getComputedStyle(test, null).height;
alert(height);
```

for ie:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var bg = body.currentStyle.height;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cc2mogpy/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Для `js` заведомо неизвестны стили, поэтому перед их получением используйте [getComputedStyle](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementById('menu_bottom').clientHeight);
```